Is the new transient storage immutable?
I just found out about EIP-1153, and that there's a new type of storage: transient, which exists in the scope of a one single transaction.
Do I understand this correctly: Contract A can write something in the transient storage, make a call to another contract B, and the contract B will be able to read from that storage?
But can all the contracts participating in the transaction also write to any location of the transient storage? Because that would make it very dangerous.
I saw multiple articles describing the work of transient storage, and some of them describe how a re-entrancy guard would work using this storage:
    modifier nonreentrant {
        assembly {
            if tload(0) { revert(0, 0) }
            tstore(0, 1)
        }
        _;
        // Unlocks the guard, making the pattern composable.
        // After the function exits, it can be called again, even in the same transaction.
        assembly {
            tstore(0, 0)
        }
    }

but what I don't understand is, wouldn't the attacker be able to change the values stored in the storage just by writing something like tstore(0, 0) when his contract is being called and then just reenter? What prevents the attacker from modifying this storage?
This would only make sense if transient storage was immutable once it is written. So my question is, it is immutable once it's written? Or just anyone participating in the transaction can modify it at any time?

Each contract has its own storage, same as normal storage. Does it make it clear?

Summary

No, transient storage is not immutable
Each contract has their own implementation of transient storage.

Deeper Explainer
Take a look at this image. 
Each contract has their own storage slot. So if Contract A calls tstore(0,7) it will store the value 7 in storage slot 0 in contract A.
Similarly, if Contract B calls tstore(0,7) it will store value 7 in storage slot 0 of Contract B. Or if it calls tstore(0,1), it will store 1 in storage slot 0.

1. Contract A can write something in the transient storage, make a call to another contract B, and the contract B will be able to read from that storage?
Not entirely true. According to the design of EIP-1153, temporary storage is similar to the persistent storage of contracts, and each contract has its own independent temporary storage space. That is, contracts A and B cannot directly share the same temporary storage space. Only contract A can access the temporary storage written by itself, and contract B can only access its own temporary storage. Therefore, when contract A calls contract B, contract B cannot access contract A's temporary storage unless DELEGATECALL is used, in which case contract B will inherit the context of contract A (including temporary storage) when it is executed.
2. Can all the contracts participating in the transaction also write to any location of the transient storage?
No, each contract has its own independent temporary storage space, which means that other contracts participating in the transaction cannot modify the temporary storage of another contract at will. Only when DELEGATECALL or CALLCODE is called, the target contract will share the caller's context (including temporary storage). Therefore, temporary storage is isolated and cannot be easily modified by other contracts.
3. Wouldn't the attacker be able to change the values stored in the storage just by writing something like tstore(0, 0) when his contract is being called and then just reenter? What prevents the attacker from modifying this storage?
An attacker cannot arbitrarily change the temporary storage of other contracts. Just like persistent storage, temporary storage is contract-private. Unless an attacker is able to operate under the same context (such as DELEGATECALL), they cannot modify the temporary storage of another contract. Therefore, when using DELEGATECALL, you do need to be careful because at this time the attacker may modify the temporary storage of the caller. Otherwise, in a normal CALL or STATICCALL, an attacker cannot access or modify the temporary storage of other contracts.
4. It is immutable once it's written? Or just anyone participating in the transaction can modify it at any time?
Temporary storage is not immutable once written, but only the contract that owns the storage can modify it. Any contract participating in the transaction cannot arbitrarily access or modify the temporary storage of another contract unless DELEGATECALL or CALLCODE is used. These situations are similar to the behavior of persistent storage, so the design of temporary storage is safe to prevent unrelated contracts from modifying it.
Summary:

Contract A and Contract B cannot directly share temporary storage unless through DELEGATECALL.
The temporary storage of each contract is private and cannot be modified at will by other contracts.
An attacker cannot perform a reentrancy attack by modifying temporary
storage under normal circumstances.
Temporary storage is not unmodifiable once written, but only the contract that owns it can modify it.

